# useEffect called many times or doesn't access updated variable. How to set the correct dependency on useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to add some behaviour on keydown event, but the useEffect is not working correctly.

Here is the code:

```
const Test = ({}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  
    const add= (sum) => {
    setValue(value+sum);
  }
  
  React.useEffect(()=> {
    const handleKeyDown = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
      console.log("keypress", value);
      if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
        add(-1);
      } else if (e.key === 'ArrowRight') {
        add(1);
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener('keydown', event => handleKeyDown(event));
    return () => {
      console.log("remove event")
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', event => handleKeyDown(event));
    };
  }, [add])
  
  return <span>Count {value}</span>

}
```

[Here is jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/zvt62h95/15/) - You can see it calling many times on keypress on the console.

If I put an empty array on useEffect dependencies, when calling add function, the value will always be 0. If I put add or value on dependency array, every time I press the key useEffect will trigger many times. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: The issue with your code is that every time the component rerenders the `add` function is recreated, this means that the `useEffect` using it as a dependency sees it as a change. If the `add` function is only used in the `useEffect` create it inside the `useEffect` and use `value` as a dependency, if the `add` function is used both inside and outside the useEffect change it to use `useCallback` so it does not get recreated each rerender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing an inline arrow function to `addEventListener` you're creating a new handler each time, and removing it doesn't work because, again, you're declaring a new function to remove--a function that was never added in the first place:

```js
// creates a new handler function every time
document.addEventListener('keydown', event => handleKeyDown(event));

// removing a function that isn't currently registered as a
// listener on the document, because it's a brand new inline function.
document.removeEventListener('keydown', event => handleKeyDown(event));
```

Another instance of your keydown listener gets added every time this renders and they never get removed, so as you interact with the app they pile up.

There's no need to create a new function just to call the existing one. Try this instead:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
```

---

Similar problem with your `add` function. Declaring `add` as an effect dependency causes the effect to run every time, because `add` gets re-declared on every render. Wrap it in a [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to prevent it from getting recreated every time:

```js
const add = React.useCallback((sum) => {
  setValue(value+sum);
}, [value]);
```

Comment: It was definitely the arrow function. I had forgotten about that. It was piling up. Thanks